# Calling page in a new tab when an item's value changes

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using apex 21.1.

I have built a report with a form. The report page(2) has another region "Param" which has item P2_DEPTNO. The form(Modal Page -3) is for creating new records and editing existing records. There is a CLOSE DIALOG process in page 3 and it has P3_DEPTNO as a value for "Items to Return" attribute. Page 2 has a DIALOG CLOSED dynamic action with a true action of SET VALUE that sets P2_DEPTNO with the value of P3_DEPTNO. This is when I should call page 4 in a new tab(when P2_DEPTNO is assigned P3_DEPTNO's value.I am calling page 4 using the code...

```
apex.navigation.openInNewWindow('f?p=&APP_ID.:4:&APP_SESSION.:::4');
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and I do not know why. However, if the dynamic action is of type Alert, it works fine and displays the alert when P2_DEPTNO's value changes. What could be the reason for that?

```
ws=ESLAM_WS

un= forhelp

pwd=Forhelppwd$

app= Call new window

pages= 2,3 and 4
```

P.S: It works if I change P2_DEPTNO's value manually. But I need it to work when the SET VALUE dynamic action set it's value.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to log in into you app, added another dynamic action event "Execute Javascript code" and entered your code without ':::4' part and it worked well for me.
so:

```
apex.navigation.openInNewWindow('f?p=&APP_ID.:4:&APP_SESSION.');
```

(also I have left an alert there that you mentioned worked anyway). If someone else fixed it meantime, I hope she/he will document here what she/he did.